# PHP preg match to store only capitalised letters, anywhere in string

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm working with an API where I receive error messages such as:

```
{"message":"Contact is suppressed. ERROR_CONTACT_SUPPRESSED"}
```

I'm trying to take these error messages and just translate them into some sort of value or code so that I can provide good responses to the user rather than just a generic error.

The only thing in the error I can see that is always true is that the last portion is capitalised. Such as `ERROR_CONTACT_SUPPRESED` or `ERROR_CONTACT_INVALID`.

I know that `preg_match` can be used to get the uppercase characters but I believe they also have to be within a certain order/number of chars from the beginning or the end. How can I get only the capitalised section back?

I found the following but just got a result of `0` which is obviously incorrect

```
$result = preg_match("/^([A-Z]+)/", $result);
echo $result . '<br />';
```

Comment: @georg that gives me a result of 1.

Comment: Yes? `1` means it does match. The correct syntax is `preg_match($re, $str, $matches)`.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if(preg_match('/[A-Z_]*/', $string, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

[Please read the documentation of preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). The function does not return the matched string as you may have expected:

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

Comment: OK so how would i go about creating the returned result as a variable to be used?

Comment: Aehm what? You ask how to assign a value to variable? Really?

Comment: Well at present $matches outputs only as a half-empty array with one value stored. So I need to clear out all the other fields and return only the one that has the stored string. I cannot do that using just var_dump and I cannot use $matches as it currently stands.

Comment: Sorry, that's too easy. Use your braincell.

Comment: I am. I have tried using .join() to make the result of $matches a variable string  rather than an array but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Well did you read the manual about arrays?

Comment: Yes I have. the .join function will not allow me to use the result of this preg_match in order to create a string variable, so at present i will have to look for another solution than preg_match as it does not allow me to use the data properly. thanks anyway.

Comment: How am I meant to not take that personally?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(preg_match('/[A-Z_]+[^a-z]/', $string, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

It will ignore capitalised letters at the beginning of words.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `preg_match` this way:

```
$str = '{"message":"Contact is suppressed. ERROR_CONTACT_SUPPRESSED"}';

preg_match("/([A-Z_]+)(?=\")/", $str, $match);
echo $result = $match[0] . '<br />';
```

The reason the pattern didn't match before was mainly because you indicated to match [A-Z] at the beginning of the line, which it wasn't =! (`^[A-Z]`). You also need to indicate the other characters present, which would include the underscore.